# How can I make flex items appear one after another vertically instead of equal height?

Tags: css, flexbox

For some reason, my 3 children inside a flex container each have equal height, but the desired behavior is that of making the items appear one after another, not filling the space they're given. See:

```css
.col-md-12 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 420px;
  background: #313131;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: green;
}

.three {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item one col-md-12"></div>
  <div class="item two col-md-12"></div>
  <div class="item three col-md12"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the three lines are each at ~33.3% of the parent's height. One at the top, one in the middle and one at the bottom.

But the way it should look is 3 lines after one another. So, from this (grey is the inner content of the child):

[image]

To this (the grey on the background is the parent):

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Probably an image to describe what you need to achieve would be more understandable.

Comment: @AlexYepes Just did!

Comment: So, from those two images in your question...you want to achieve the one on the bottom? And that big square in the middle would represent the 3 lines that occupies the height of their parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `flex-flow: column`.

```css
.col-md-12 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 420px;
  background: #313131;
  padding: 0;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: green;
}

.three {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item one col-md-12"></div>
  <div class="item two col-md-12"></div>
  <div class="item three col-md-12"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, but the children need to be a `flex`.

Comment: Right. Fixed the answer above ^

Comment: I added `flex-flow: column`, which makes flex elements flow in columns. I'd advise reading the docs for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow

Comment: because of the removal of `flex` on the child elements

Comment: No, that hasn't gotten anything to do with it. Look, I changed the answer above so the child elements have `flex`, it works the same.

Comment: but you din't explain why you removed  `flex: 0 0 100%;`

Comment: Oh, just because `flex: 0 0 100%` makes the elements span to the full width of the container.

Comment: @barhatsor I've accepted the answer given it's what I asked, but it doesn't work on local, even if `computed` values are equal to yours.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the wrap to no wrap or change the width to 33.3%

```css
 .col{
   width: 100%; 
   height: 100%;
 }

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 420px;
  background: #313131;
  padding: 0;display: flex;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: green;
}

.three {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col one"></div>
  <div class="col two"></div>
  <div class="col three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I've specified, it's "vertically", also, I can't have a set height on the children.

Comment: I checked a bit, and all i needed to do was flex-direction: column; check snippet